# Example of non-trivial number field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

(i) Give an example of non-trivial number field $K$ (so $[K:\mathbb Q]<\infty$) and a proper subring $R$ of $K$ such that $K$ is the fraction field of $R$, but $R$ is not an
order in $K$.

(ii) Given that there exist solutions where $K$, $L_1$, $L_2$ are quadratic, give an example of two number fields $L_1$ and $L_2$ contained in a bigger number field $M$ such that $O_{L_1L_2}\neq O_{L_1}O_{L_2}$.

Comment: Try an extension of the $p$-adic rationals for $R$. But yeah, the site ethos is such that simply copy/pasting something that looks like homework will get a non-encouraging response. Show what you have tried, and people will be more eager to help you.

Comment: @Jyrki, an extension of the $p$-adic rationals, as a proper subring of a number field?

Comment: I think Jyrki may have been joking with that $\,p-$adic extension.

Comment: I did forget to specify rational $p$-adic **integers**. Why wouldn't $$R=\{a+bi\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\cap\mathbb{Z}_p\}$$ work! It is admittedly unlikely that such a "hint" would prove to be very useful in this case :-)

Comment: This is exactly the same question you posted before. Don't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following steps lead to an example for 2: (Marcus Exercise 2.31)

1. Show that $\frac{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}}{2}$ is an algebraic integer.
2. What are $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})}$?
3. Conclude.